# how to create ad user with some requirements in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have to create adUser's. The password should be the first 6 characters of the ID card and the last name. I should divide the full name into first name and last name.

This is my script, but it did not work:

```
$Userslist = import-csv "C:\teacherslist.csv"

ForEach ($User in $Userslist){
    $name = $User.FullName -split '\s+'
    $firstName = $name[0]
    $lastName = $name[1]
    $pass = $User.IDcard.subString(0,6)+$lastName


    New-ADUser -name $User.StaffID 
        -GivenName $FirstName 
        -Surname $LastName 
        -DisplayName $user.FullName 
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -force) 
        -Path 'OU=Teacher,DC=school,DC=com' 
        -HomeDrive 'F:'
        -changePasswordAtLogon $true 

}
```

Comment: Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are probably getting parsing issues with your arguments on different lines like that. I understand that it makes is easier to read, but PowerShell doesn't know that the next line contains another parameter for your New-ADUser cmdlet unless you put a backtick at the end of each line (**must be the last character of the line**).

If you want to keep your parameters organized like that a better way to do it is to assign them to a variable as a hashtable and then splat the hashtable as your parameters for New-ADUser.

```
ForEach ($User in $Userslist){
    $name = $User.FullName -split '\s+'
    $firstName = $name[0]
    $lastName = $name[1]
    $pass = $User.IDcard.subString(0,6)+$lastName


   $Params = @{'name' = $User.StaffID;
        'GivenName' = $FirstName;
        'Surname' = $LastName;
        'DisplayName' = $user.FullName;
        'AccountPassword' = (ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -force);
        'Path' = 'OU=Teacher,DC=school,DC=com';
        'HomeDrive' = 'F:';
        'changePasswordAtLogon' = $true}

   New-ADUser @Params

}
```